# How to access BigQuery table metadata in DBT using jinja?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, dbt

I'd like to access the last modified time column from the metadata of a BigQuery table that acts as a source. I want to create a generic test that checks if the last modified date of the source table is equal to today.

In BigQuery you can access this data in this way:

```
SELECT
last_modified_time
FROM `project.dataset.__TABLES__`
WHERE table_id = 'table_id'
```

My goal is to make the project.dataset dynamic depending on the model this test is applied to. Similarly, I'd like for table_id to be dynamic.

Given that DBT mentions on their documentation that the dataset of BigQuery is similar in definition to 'schema', I tried this but it didn't work.

```
{% test last_modified_time(schema, model) %}

SELECT
  last_modified_time
FROM `{{ database }}.{{ schema }}.__TABLES__`
WHERE table_id = {{ model }}

{% endtest %}
```

What this does is it renders the project name for both database and schema.
Also, model will (of course) render the project.dataset.table_id path while I only need the table_id.

I'm fairly new to DBT but I couldn't find anything that resembles what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few changes you need to make:

1. Your generic test is accepting an argument named `schema`, which [dbt won't provide](https://docs.getdbt.com/guides/legacy/writing-custom-generic-tests#generic-tests-with-standard-arguments) when you execute the test. The test should only accept `model`, and then you'll want to config your yaml file so the test is on the model (not on a column):

   ```yaml
   models:
       - name: my_model
         tests:
             - last_modified_time
   ```
2. The `model` argument is a [Relation](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/dbt-classes#relation), and you can use that to grab the database/project, schema/dataset, and identifier (the materialized name) of the model.
3. Tests fail if they return any records. So your test will always fail. You need to compare the last_modified_time to the current date, and only return records that are older than the current date.

Putting that all together:

```sql
{% test last_modified_time(model) %}

with t as (
    SELECT last_modified_time
    FROM `{{ model.database }}.{{ model.schema }}.__TABLES__`
    WHERE table_id = '{{ model.identifier }}'
)
select *
from t
where t.last_modified_time < current_date()

{% endtest %}
```

Comment: Hi there! Thanks a lot! Point 2 is what makes it work for me. You're right in that it wasn't a valid test yet, I just couldn't figure out how to render the project.dataset part using 'model'. This should solve it.

Answer (score 0):

I tinkered with your solution for a little bit and this works flawlessly.
Thank you so much!

```
{% test last_modified_time(model) %}

WITH t AS (
SELECT DATE(TIMESTAMP_MILLIS(last_modified_time)) AS lmt
FROM `{{ model.database }}.{{ model.schema }}.__TABLES__`
WHERE table_id = '{{ model.identifier }}'
)

SELECT
lmt
FROM t
WHERE lmt < CURRENT_DATE()

{% endtest %}
```